# Display contents of an array, take user input and verify, repeat. Java

Tags: java, arrays, input

I know this is a simple question but its just not clicking for me. somebody put me out of my misery and answer this for me... I'm trying to display the contents of an array, have the user type in the output, verify they typed it in correctly and cycle through the array repeating these steps. Thanks in advance for a good answers! I need a loop to do the following steps.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int nextArr;
    String Rj_in;
    String[] Two = {"This", "is", "a", "second", "test", "This is a second test"};

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Type these: ");
    System.out.println(Two[0]);
    Rj_in = in.nextLine();
    if ((Two[0]).equals(Rj_in)) {
        System.out.println("Thats it!");
    }
    System.out.println(Two[1]);
    Rj_in = in.nextLine();
    if ((Two[1]).equals(Rj_in)) {
        System.out.println("Thats it!");
    }
    System.out.println(Two[2]);
    Rj_in = in.nextLine();
    if ((Two[2]).equals(Rj_in)) {
        System.out.println("Thats it!");
    }
    System.out.println(Two[3]);
    Rj_in = in.nextLine();
    if ((Two[3]).equals(Rj_in)) {
        System.out.println("Thats it!");
    }
    System.out.println(Two[4]);
    Rj_in = in.nextLine();
    if ((Two[4]).equals(Rj_in)) {
        System.out.println("Thats it!");
    }
    System.out.println(Two[5]);
    Rj_in = in.nextLine();
    if ((Two[5]).equals(Rj_in)) {
        System.out.println("Thats it!");
    }
    System.out.println(Two[6]);
    Rj_in = in.nextLine();
    if ((Two[6]).equals(Rj_in)) {
        System.out.println("Thats it!");
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Well, how about you just try it yourself? There's plenty of resources available on beginner-stuff in java e.g. the [java nuts and bolts-tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html). SO is not a coding-service

Comment: Just write a loop to iterate over the array.

Answer (score 0):

In your program you index your arrays with consecutive integers:

```
System.out.println(Two[0]);
Rj_in = in.nextLine();
if ((Two[0]).equals(Rj_in)) {
    System.out.println("Thats it!");
}

System.out.println(Two[1]);
Rj_in = in.nextLine();
if ((Two[1]).equals(Rj_in)) {
    System.out.println("Thats it!");
}
```

A `for` loop can do this for you:

```
for(int i = 0; i < Two.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(Two[i]);
    Rj_in = in.nextLine();
    if ((Two[i]).equals(Rj_in)) {
        System.out.println("Thats it!");
    }
}
```

See how we use a variable called `i` and increment it in the loop header until we reach the length of the array, and we use that `i` to index the arrays.

You could do it with a `while` loop as well, but a `for` loop is nicer.

```
int i = 0;
while(i < Two.length) {
    System.out.println(Two[i]);
    Rj_in = in.nextLine();
    if ((Two[i]).equals(Rj_in)) {
        System.out.println("Thats it!");
    }
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Matt! You are the man! Thank you for taking the time to write this out and explain it! I'm new to programming and tech in general. I have been trying to figure this out for a hot second and it just never clicked. Once again, I sincerely appreciate your time brother!

Comment: Sure thing Brad, sometimes it just takes a worked example. :)